# Converting Byte[] to Double

Tags: c#

I have a byte[8], which is actually a sequential number. It comes from the RowVersion in a database.

I am really just concerned about the last 4 bytes of the 8 byte array.

I am trying to do this:

```
 Version = BitConverter.ToDouble(t.Version,4)
```

'Version' is a double. But, I get an error saying that:

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the
>   collection. Check array index and length.

The value of my 'Version' is:

> [0]0 [1]0 [2]0 [3]0 [4]0 [5]0 [6]12 [7]102

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: double is 8 bytes, maybe you want `float` instead

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx) - "The ToDouble method converts the bytes from index startIndex to startIndex + 7 to a Double value," 4 + 7 is bigger than the size of your initial array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`double` requires 8 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx), so you should get only one from your entire `byte[]`:

```
BitConverter.ToDouble(input, 0);
```

returns

```
3.7179659497173697E+183
```

***Update***

But because you're saying it's a `rowversion` value, you should convert it to `long` instead of `double`:

```
BitConverter.ToInt64(input, 0);
```

returns

```
7353252291589177344
```

Comment: This is what I tried originally, Marcin, but noticed that when I ordered by this number - it gave strange results. I'm assuming the '+183' bit was the issue, and the number was too large to sort on?

Comment: It's `rowversion`, so you should use `Int64` (vel. `long`) instead of `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
double[] array= bytearray.Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();
```

Update:

```
BitConverter.ToDouble(yournumber, 0);
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OPs looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to convert the byte[] into a number, so that I can sort on it, and the first 4 bytes are never used - or won't be, as the number of record to get to that size, is a bit big. So, I just care about the first (last?) 4 bytes. And then I want to convert the byte[4] into a number.

Comment: I think an 8 byte array is too big for the int, and maybe even for a double. So, I am first trying to reduce the byte size, and then convert.